# SQL Script to Delete Specific Rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL table with 3 columns 'latitude', 'longitude', 'status'. I would like to create a script that runs through all rows in the table, starting with the first row of latitude/longitude and deletes all other latitude/longitude rows that are less than 0.3 difference, then update the 'status' column for that first row as 'completed'. Then it will do the same for the second row of latitude/longitude, then third row, and so on, until all rows have 'completed' in the 'status' column. This is the query that should be used for deleting the rows:

```
delete from create_concert_xml_job 
where abs({latitude1} - latitude) <= 0.3 AND abs({longitude1} - longitude) <= 0.3;
```

`{latitude1}`and `{longitude}` are from the row that that the other rows are being compared to.

Can anyone please help me with this?

UPDATE: for example say these are the lat/long of the first 4 rows:

3.5/7.5

4.5/6.5

3.6/7.6

4.6/6.6

so when the script runs the first row it should delete all rows returned from this query:

delete from create_concert_xml_job where abs(3.5 - latitude) <= 0.3 AND abs(7.5 - longitude) <= 0.3;

Which will result in row 3 being deleted. Then it will run row 2 and use the query:

delete from create_concert_xml_job where abs(4.5 - latitude) <= 0.3 AND abs(6.5 - longitude) <= 0.3;

Which will result in row 4 being deleted.

Comment: what is that `latitude1`?

Comment: If you're going to use braces for `{latitude1}` why not for `latitude`?

Comment: why do you want to set status after deleting the row??

Comment: @HendryTanaka {latitude1}and {longitude1} are from the row that that the other rows are being compared to. It is just a placeholder for the query I have above.

Comment: @Fred-ii- {latitude1} is just a placeholder for the latitude that will be used to compare the other rows to delete. 'latitude' will be the latitudes that will be deleted.

Comment: @JayakarthikAppasamy the status is for the row that the other rows were compared to, not for the deleted rows. For example after the script runs the first row of latitude/longitude and deletes the rows that meet the query then it will update the status for that first row. That first row will not be deleted.

Comment: @AngeloRodriguez I don't get your idea. latitude1 is a temporary variable right?

Comment: @HendryTanaka I updated with more info above

Comment: @AngeloRodriguez , just one question and the last from me. How did you get latitude1 or longitude1 value?

Comment: @HendryTanaka it is from the rows when they are processed. So from the example I gave, when the first row is processed latitude1=3.5 and longitude1=7.5 . When the row second is processed latitude1=4.5 and longitude1=6.5

Comment: @AngeloRodriguez No no...I mean, are you using mysql right? May I know  what is the syntax to get latitude1 or longitude1.

Comment: @HendryTanaka nevermind. My was able to have my programmer do it. Thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found other way around. You can use

> > UPDATE `create_concert_xml_job` SET `latitude`= (latitude1-latitude), `longitude`= (longitude1-longitude) , `status`='completed';

Later you'll have a table which contains data where you can fire a query to DELETE where latitude < 0.3

> > DELETE FROM `create_concert_xml_job` WHERE `latitude`<='0.3' AND `longitude`<='0.3';

Comment: Is this the answer are you looking at?

Comment: @HendryTanaka no this is not what I am looking for. I want to first take the latitude/longitude of first row and delete all other rows that are within 0.3. Then I want to take latitude/longitude of second row and delete all other rows that are within 0.3. Then third row, and so on until all rows have been processed